# Checking Database state before updating a record

Tags: update, database

Is there anyway to check the current database state (version or whatever applicable term) of a record, before performing DML on that?

Scenario :

- user 1 retrieves record A
- user 2 retrieves record A
- user 2 updates record A
- user 1 updates record A

In above, user 1 is updating an older version of record A since that version is in memory before user 2 updates it. Is there anyway to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [SystemModstamp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm) but this has 1 second granularity so there is that time window when two updates would generate the same value. You could also look at [LastModifiedById](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm) assuming your users are only logged in once.

Alternatively, if you hold on to the original version of the record on your initial retrieve, then lock the record by using [for update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm) in a requery at the start of your save, you can compare the fields you are updating (between the original and requeried) to see if anyone else has changed them if that is the problem you are trying to avoid.

Comment: I think `SystemModStamp` will do the job almost same as a database state number. I'll give a try on this, Thanks for the idea @KeithC

Comment: @highfive Suggest you check LastModifiedById too - although a 1 second window seems low risk if there are say 1,000 users working it is going to get hit pretty quickly.

Comment: Yes, thanks again. Actually this is for investigating an unexpected field resetting. Initial step looking forward is to tell user "hey there's an updated version of this, please refresh" while making some logs or mails for debugging. To do that tracking the database state difference of the record is the key and fields you have stated are actually what I need, I feel.